# How to control table section title's indentation in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7

I suppose that the iOS 7 convention is to make the table cell separators start where the text starts. I wrote the following code to do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.separatorInset = 50.0;
}
```

The problem is that my section titles also get shifted by the same amount. How would I control the indentation of the section titles independently from the cell separators? I would prefer that the section titles be left aligned.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't set the separatorInset for the UITableView. Instead, set the separatorInset for the UITableViewCell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
[cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 0, 0)];
```

Or do it in the story board if you prefer:

[image]